# Angular 5: ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I've checked and compiled 12 times now and can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error in my console:

```
ERROR Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
at e.selectRootElement (main.bundle.js:1)
at Sn (main.bundle.js:1)
at zr (main.bundle.js:1)
at Lr (main.bundle.js:1)
at Object.io [as createRootView] (main.bundle.js:1)
at t.create (main.bundle.js:1)
at t.create (main.bundle.js:1)
at e.bootstrap (main.bundle.js:1)
at main.bundle.js:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'App Component';
}
```

I've read through several others who experienced this error and it was usually due to the index.html file not using the correct selector name. I've checked my code and it looks correct to me.

Comment: it works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxxlbh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It runs fine for me as well when I preview using bg build serve. However when I compile it for deployment, I get the above error. I tested locally and on AWS, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: ng build serve*

Comment: I generated a new project using the cli. I didn't change anything in the project, runs locally. After building for deployment, I get the same console error.

Answer (score -1):

Added a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HfAIFU0Fzc8YzTEaUlUM?p=preview),
From 4.3.x HttpModule available as HttpClientModule at `'@angular/common/http'`

Comment: I tried that. It still doesn't work after building and exporting the project. Same error. It does work when I just compile using ng serve. But after I export the files using ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing none and test the project, I get the error in my original post.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have added **app-root** in index.html

```
<body>

<app-root></app-root>

</body>
```